# Android studio one item in list padding

Tags: android, list, layout, padding

I need to move my list down.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp">
```

It applies margin to every element on the list. I only need it to be applied to first element of the list

Comment: There is no list in the example of the code you gave. What type of view are you using for that list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding margin to your list item, try adding margin to your rootview i.e listview or recyclerview whichever you are using